# I’m using Dash and i want to remove the time from the Service date column 2020-03-26T00:00:00 to this format2020-03-26

Tags: python, datetime, plotly, plotly-dash

Hi I’m using excel sheet to upload it to dash and under Service date column right now it shows like this :2020-03-26T00:00:00 but I want to remove the time part please let me know if you need more information

here is my code from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html, Input, Output, callback

```
import pandas as pd
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import os
import dateutil.parser as dparser
"""

"""
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/x/Desktop/Instrument Statistical Analysis/DASH by potly/Instrument Statistical Analysis_more.csv', skiprows=\[1,2,3,4\])

df = df.rename(columns={'SNR: (2600 - 2500 cm-1) ':'SNR: (2600 - 2500 cm-1)'})

df= df.fillna("---")

\#df\['Service date'\] = pd.to_datetime(df\['Service date'\], errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df\['Service date'\] = df\['Service date'\].replace('---', pd.NaT)
df\['Service date'\] = pd.to_datetime(df\['Service date'\]).dt.date.astype(str)

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=\[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP\])

for index, date_str in enumerate(df\['Service date'\]):
try:
df\['Service date'\] = pd.to_datetime(df\['Service date'\], format='%Y/%m/%d', errors='coerce')

    except ValueError:
        try:
            df.at[index, 'Service date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_str, format= '%d/%m/%Y')
        except ValueError:
            
         df.at[index, 'Service date'] = pd.to_datetime(date_str, format='%d/%m/%y')

print('I')
print(df\['Service date'\])
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=\[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP\])

app.layout = dbc.Container(\[
html.Img(src=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'logo.png'), style={'float': 'center', 'width': '150px', 'margin-top': '40px'}),
dcc.Markdown('# Instrument Statistical Analysis', style={'textAlign':'center','margin-top': '10px'}),

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Label("Client name"),
            Client_drop := dcc.Dropdown([str(x) for x in sorted(df.Client.astype(str).unique())], multi=True)
    
        ], 
        width=3),
    
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Label("Type"),
            type_drop := dcc.Dropdown(options=[{'label': t, 'value': t} for t in df['Type'].unique()],
                                      multi=True, clearable=True)
        ], width=2),
        
    
    
    
        # dbc.Col([
        #     dbc.Label("Service Date"),
        #     date_drop := dcc.Dropdown([str(x) for x in sorted(df['Service date'].astype(str).unique())], multi=True)
        # ], width=3),
    
    
        
    
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Label("Year"),
            year_drop := dcc.Dropdown([int(x) for x in sorted(df['Service date'].dropna().dt.year.unique())], multi=True)
        ],
        width=2),
    
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Label("Month"),
            month_drop := dcc.Dropdown([str(x) for x in sorted(df['Service date'].dropna().dt.strftime('%B').unique())], multi=True)
        ],
        width=2),
    
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Label("Day"),
            day_drop := dcc.Dropdown([int(x) for x in sorted(df['Service date'].dropna().dt.day.unique())], multi=True)
        ],
            width=2),
            dbc.Col([
            dbc.Label("Number of rows"),
            row_drop := dcc.Dropdown(value=10, clearable=False, style={'width':'50%'},
                                     options=[10, 25, 50, 100]),
                                     
        ], 
        width=3),
    
    
    ], 
    className='mt-3 mb-4'),
    
    my_table := dash_table.DataTable(
        columns=[
            {'name': 'Type', 'id': 'Type', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Sheet', 'id': 'Sheet', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Client', 'id': 'Client', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Service date', 'id': 'Service date', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Reason for service', 'id': 'Reason for service', 'type': 'any','format': {'specifier': '%Y-%m-%d'}},
            {'name': 'RemScan Serial number', 'id': 'RemScan Serial\#', 'type': 'numeric'},
            {'name': 'Checked by:', 'id': 'Checked by:', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'User ID', 'id': 'User ID', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Password', 'id': 'Password', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'PDA / Tablet \nOperating System', 'id': 'PDA / Tablet Operating System', 'type': 'text'},
            {'name': 'Background Cap \n(Minimum requirement = 4500 @ Gain = 255)', 'id': 'Background Cap (Minimum requirement = 4500 @ Gain = 255)', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Polystyrene P/S Cap (Minimum requirement = 4000 @ Gain = 255)', 'id': 'Polystyrene P/S Cap (Minimum requirement = 4000 @ Gain = 255)', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'SNR: (1142 - 1042 cm-1) \n(Recommended requirement = 4500)', 'id': 'SNR: (1142 - 1042 cm-1) (Recommended requirement = 4500)', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'SNR: (2600 - 2500 cm-1) '.strip(), 'id': 'SNR: (2600 - 2500 cm-1)', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Centre burst intensity \n(Interferogram) (Minimum requirement = 20,)', 'id': 'Centre burst intensity (Interferogram) (Minmum requirement =20,000)', 'type': 'numeric'},
            {'name': 'Single beam spectrum \n(Counts: 4200-4500 / Total Counts)x100 (Minimum requirement =1%)', 'id': 'Single beam spectrum (Counts: 4200-4500 / Total Counts)x100                  (Minimum requirement =1%)', 'type': 'any'},
            {'name': 'Single beam spectrum \n(Counts: 2600-3000 / Total Counts)x100 (Minimum requirement = 7%)', 'id': 'Single beam spectrum (Counts: 2600-3000 / Total Counts)x100                  (Minimum requirement = 7%)', 'type': 'any'}
        ],
        style_cell={
        'minWidth': '450px',  # minimum width of cells
        'maxWidth': '400px',  # maximum width of cells
        'whiteSpace': 'normal',  # allow wrapping of cell content
        'textAlign': 'center',},  # center align cell content
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        filter_action='custom',
        page_size=10,
        style_data={
            'width': '150px', 'minWidth': '150px', 'maxWidth': '150px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
        }
    ),

\])
from datetime import datetime

@callback(
Output(my_table, 'data'),
Output(my_table, 'page_size'),
Input(Client_drop, 'value'),
Input(row_drop, 'value'),
Input(type_drop, 'value'),
Input(year_drop, 'value'),
Input(month_drop, 'value'),
Input(day_drop, 'value')
)
def update_dropdown_options(Client_v, row_v, type_v,year_v, month_v, day_v):
dff = df.copy()

    if Client_v:
        dff = dff[dff.Client.isin(Client_v)]
    
    if type_v:
        dff = dff[dff.Type.isin(type_v)]
    
    if year_v:
        dff = dff[dff['Service date'].dt.year.isin(year_v)]
    
    if month_v:
        dff = dff[dff['Service date'].dt.month_name().isin(month_v)]
    
    if day_v:
        dff = dff[dff['Service date'].dt.day.isin(day_v)]
    
     #dff['Service date'] = dff['Service date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    
    return dff.to_dict('records'), row_v

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True, port=8001)
```

i tried doing this to work but did not work

```
my_table := dash_table.DataTable(
columns=\[
\# ... column definitions ...
{'name': 'Service date', 'id': 'Service date', 'type': 'datetime',
'format': {'specifier': '%Y-%m-%d'}}
\# ... remaining column definitions ...
\],
\# ... other parameters ...
)
```